# Как передать массив, созданный в JavaScript'e, в PНP и записать в бд MySQL?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, php

Создаю массив отсюда. Эта у меня Аjах или jQuery корзина. Даже сам запутался.

```
Arrays.push(thisID);
var t = $('.cart-total span').html();
t = Number(t) + Number(qiymet)
$('.cart-total span').html(t.toFixed(2));
$('#total-hidden-charges').val(t.toFixed(2));
$('#left_bar .cart-info').append('<div class="shopp" id="each-' + thisID + '"><span class="label">' + mal_name + '</span><span style="float:left;width:102px;border-right-width: 2px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-color: #ccc;"><span class="az"></span><span class="mal_say">1</span>&nbsp;' + eded + '<span class="cox"></span></span><span class="price"><em>' + qiymet + '</em> man.</span><span class="endir"><input type="text" id="end"  size="3" style="height:8px; font-size:11px; margin-top:-6px;"/> man.</span><span class="hesab" id="hesab"><em>' + qiymet + '</em> man.</span><img src="img/remove.png" class="remove" /><br class="all" /></div>');
```

а в массив толко .label пока запихнул, это типа название товара
ребята у меня массив не правилный помоему.

```
$('#save').livequery('click', function () {
    var newarr = new Array();
    arr = $('.label');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    newarr.push($(arr[i]).html());
    alert(newarr);
    $.post('save.php', {
        arr: newarr
    }, function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
});
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот мой пхп, который принимает массив.

```
<? 
if (isset($_POST['arr'])) {
echo '<div id="iframe">
    <div class="shopp">
        <span class="label">'.$_POST['arr'].'</span>
        <span class="mal_sayi">5 kletka</span>
        <span class="mal_umum_qiymet">цена</span>
        <span class="endir">скидка</span>
        <span class="hesab">сумма</span>
        <br class="all" />
    </div><br>
</div>';
}

?>
```

Массив я принимаю, но в цикл не могу запихать, выводится только один товар. Если можно без массива засунуть, все это в бд, то как?

Comment: а где у вас цкил в php?

Comment: Вот этого цикла не могу составить.

Comment: Ребята. Я все эта уже прочитал, я не понимаю толком, нада помощ другого.

Comment: а вы прочитайте так чтобы понимали. Помощь другого "чего" или "кого", что вам конкретно сейчас в данный момент нужно сделать?

Comment: создать массив не получается?

Comment: Эта у меня Аjах или JQuery корзина
Вы хоть думайте что пишите, корзина она не может быть библотекой ибо же технологией. Корзина это то место, куда юзер добавил свой товар (ибо же это скорее всего не имя даже, а код товара), т.е. будет массив примерно такой $arr = array("36","26","39"). Хранить это лучше в куках, а потом передавать на сервер и уже обрабатывать как вам душе угодно.

Comment: Да))).Если можно.
Вот ета уменя принимает название товара при добавление товара в корзину,
тепер нада все название товаров запихать в массив и передать в пхп и оттуда копию в БД и копию в цикл типа do while
<span class="label">' + mal_name + '</span>

Comment: я бы вообще ставил метки в БД какой товар юзер выбрал, а потом выводил.

Comment: А как поставить метки))).
Эта я для своего магазина пишу, любителский))
И прошу не сердитесь на меня, не буду успокавливать))).

Answer (score 1):

для начала проверить что пришло `print_r($_POST["arr"])` ни мешало бы, и как по мне, то в бд лучше пихать `id`-шники покупок, чем какой-то кусок `html`. А ваш код и не состоит из какого-либо цикла, тогда так:

```
if (isset($_POST['arr'])) {

    $arr = $_POST['arr'];

    foreach ($arr as $val) {

        echo '<div id="iframe">
                <div class="shopp">
                    <span class="label">'.$val.'</span>
                     <span class="mal_sayi">5 kletka</span>
                     <span class="mal_umum_qiymet">цена</span>
                     <span class="endir">скидка</span>
                     <span class="hesab">сумма</span>
                     <br class="all" />
               </div><br>
        </div>';

          }
    }
```

Я так понял это вывод, а ввод в БД уже совсем другая история, и да, там тоже без цикла навряд ли у вас что-нть толковое выйдет.

Когда юзер добавляет товар в корзину, естественно в вашей БД должна быть таблица корзина

```
`user_id` `product_id` `values`
```

Вот каждый раз когда он кликает по какому-нть продукту записывайте в эту таблицу id этого юзера, код товара и кол-во.

напр. это так будет выглядеть:

```
`user_id` | `product_id` | `values`
    2     |      28      |    3
```

еще один какой-то товар добавил:

```
`user_id` | `product_id` | `values`
    2     |      28      |    3
    2     |      34      |    1
```

Все, для вывода просто выводите эти данные. Связи это!!!

Соответственно юзер может и удалять вещи из корзины.

Конечно есть некоторые нюансы в плане того что пользователь должен быть зерегестрирован. Просто есть такие магазины в который и без регистрации можно добавить товары в корзину, это уже куками делается.

Comment: Вы правы))) с вашим кодом тоже нечего не вышло((.
Я могу отправить весь НТМЛ код если хотите помочь.
Я уже 2 день копаю гугл, и не могу решить проблему.
у меня ява код показывает массив на alert() я проверял.
а на save.php показывает толко один запись, последнюю добавленную.
Хотите помоч? если не отберу у вас ценную время
Вы бы мне очень помогли.

Помоему здес трудного нечего нет, это просто мне очень трудновата.
Кады тоже у меня понятные все попрядку

Comment: с вашим код у меня выдает вот эта

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in z:\home\localhost\www\ambar\save.php on line 12

Comment: я еще не написал код для добавление в БД, уменя же пока ета не готова.
если я смогу вывести массив через пхп на дисплей то в БД тоже смогу засунуть.(я так думаю)))

Comment: а если массиву сделать серилизацию и записать в БД?Так разве не лучше?

Comment: С нашим кодом... Я же написал проверяйте переменную print_r( $arr ), а потом уже циклите если там массив конечно же оказался.

Comment: Кстати да, сериализация тривиальная вещь, кто владеет, тот не мучается.

Comment: Как удобно так и сделаем. если нада серилизация то давйте сделаем.
Я проверял print_r($arr) туда попадает толко один товар, которы я последний выбрал.

Comment: Ну вот вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. А давайте вы подучите мат часть? Напр. вот тут: http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/serialize/ и тут http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ ?